# Sonata admin. How to pass post data to another controller

Tags: symfony, crud, sonata-admin

I'm newby in Symfony, so excuse my ignorance.

I have a parent Entity "Article" and sub-entites like "Page", "News" etc. They have common fields like title, date etc.

I created initial form for Article (in ArticleAdmin class) where's possible to choose title and type of sub-entity, and tried to call sub-entity's Admin class and pass there POST data. But this didn't work, because createAction in Controller is responsible for both the form rendering and for its processing, and when i try to override it in my createAction() i get an error "Error: Call to private method Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::setFormTheme()"

Here's my code:

ArticleAdmin - parent entity

```
<?php

namespace A26\CMS\ContentBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;

class ArticleAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('title', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Title'
        ))
        ->add('slug', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Slug'
        ))
        ->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Page'      => 'Text Page',
                'News'      => 'News'
            ),
        ));
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('title');
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title')
        ->add('is_publish');
}

protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('title');
}
}
?>
```

PageAdmin - sub-entity

```
<?php

namespace A26\CMS\PagesBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

class PageAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

// Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->tab('Content')
            ->with('Content')
                ->add('title', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Title'
                ))
                ->add('content', CKEditorType::class, array(
                    'label'         => 'Content'
                ))
            ->end()
        ->end();
}

// Fields to be shown on filter forms
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('title');
}

// Fields to be shown on lists
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title');
}

// Fields to be shown on show action
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('title');
}
}
?>
```

ArticleAdmin Controller - i copied CRUDController and replaced block

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {...}

```
<?php

namespace A26\CMS\ContentBundle\Controller;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;

class ArticleAdminController extends Controller
{

public function createAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    // the key used to lookup the template
    $templateKey = 'edit';

    $this->admin->checkAccess('create');

    $class = new \ReflectionClass($this->admin->hasActiveSubClass() ? $this->admin->getActiveSubClass() : $this->admin->getClass());

    if ($class->isAbstract()) {
        return $this->render(
            'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:select_subclass.html.twig',
            array(
                'base_template' => $this->getBaseTemplate(),
                'admin' => $this->admin,
                'action' => 'create',
            ),
            null,
            $request
        );
    }

    $object = $this->admin->getNewInstance();

    $preResponse = $this->preCreate($request, $object);
    if ($preResponse !== null) {
        return $preResponse;
    }

    $this->admin->setSubject($object);

    /** @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
    $form = $this->admin->getForm();
    $form->setData($object);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $response = $this->forward("A26CMSPagesBundle:PageAdmin:create", array('_sonata_admin' => $this->container->get('request')->get('_sonata_admin')));
        dump($response);
        die();
    }

    $formView = $form->createView();
    // set the theme for the current Admin Form
    $this->setFormTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFormTheme());

    return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate($templateKey), array(
        'action' => 'create',
        'form' => $formView,
        'object' => $object,
    ), null);
}
}
```

Help, please! Maybe it can be implemented another way?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The way you make your $response is correct but now you need to return it at the end of the action or the forward will never happen

Answer (score 0):

Regarding error you getting,

Instead :

```
$this->setFormTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFormTheme());
```

Use :

```
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFormTheme());
```

Or :

```
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension')->renderer->setTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFormTheme());
```